# Woocommerce - Hide price of attributes on the cart

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to hide some information (plus sign, currancy Symbol and Price) about product variation from cart and order page, right know it displays like this:

```
<dl class="variation">
<dt class="variation-CoresdeGravao">Cores de Gravação:</dt>
    <dd class="variation-CoresdeGravao"><p>Uma cor de gravação&nbsp;&nbsp;+<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">R$</span>0,83</span></p>
    </dd>
```

Price and currency I was able to hide using css but the plus sign comes with the variation description and I just can't find where this comes from.

In the `cart-item-data.php` file, there is this code:

```
<dl class="variation">
    <?php foreach ( $item_data as $data ) : ?>
        <dt class="<?php echo sanitize_html_class( 'variation-' . $data['key'] ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $data['key'] ); ?>:</dt>
        <dd class="<?php echo sanitize_html_class( 'variation-' . $data['key'] ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( $data['display'] ) ); ?></dd>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
```

But I don't know much about php so I was not able to find where this plus sign comes from, and since it doens't have a class of its own I was not able to hide it with css.